# Python: Add compiled object to Memcached

Tags: python, memcached, python-memcached

I try to add a compiled object to Memcached that is regularly used. The compiled object does never change.

```py
cache.set(eq, compile(eq, '<string>', 'eval'), 365*24*60*60)
```

But get the following error message:

> Can't pickle < class 'code' >: attribute lookup code on builtins failed

Is there any solution to this problem or an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use marshal module which is specifically designed for internal object serialization

```
cache.set(eq, marshal.dumps(compile(eq, '<string>', 'eval')), 365*24*60)
  ...
eval(marshal.loads(cache.get(eq)))
```

alternatively you can store the source

```
cache.set(eq, eq, 365*24*60)
   ...
eval(cache.get(eq))
```

Either way you may need to evaluate potential security risks of executing code retrieved from external cache.